# Calculate intersection point between two lines

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm doing a function to calculate the intersection point between two lines with this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_two_points_on_each_line

Sometimes it works, sometimes it gives strange result.

This is my function:

```
getInterSectionFromTwoLines: function (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {


        var pXTopRow = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4)) - ((x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4));
        var pxBottomRow = ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4));

        var pX = pXTopRow / pxBottomRow;

        var pYTopRow = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4));
        var pYBottomRow = ((x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4));

        var pY = pYTopRow / pYBottomRow;

        console.log(pX);
        return [pX, pY];
      },
```

[image]

An example where this function gives faulty result:

```
x1 302120.023
y1 53.370760941332236
x2 302929.722
y2 48.61111111111111
x3 302120.023
y3 40.123322394835846
x4 302929.722
y4 48.35264212015722
```

This will output:

```
pX = 302945.8342930201
pY = 48.51639829469884
```

As you can see, pX is higher than x4 and x2. This cannot be possible. Have I made a misstake in my function?

Comment: You should state more precisely what you are trying ot do and what is your problem. I don't want to debug and understand a program. 4 points can lead to 6 different lines, so it is not easy to see which lines you are taking into account...

Comment: @Martigan I added a picture where you can see the lines.

Comment: Also, there is no need for the intersection's $x$ to lie between $x_2$ and $x_4$. If the lines are almost parallell, the intersection will be very far from the line points you specified.

Comment: @PerStröm You are assuming in your picture that: $y_4>y_2$ and $y_1>y_3$, and that $x_1=x_3$, $x_2=x_4$. In your calculus, the $x$ relations holds, but you have $y_4<y_2$. Numbers do not conform your picture, and you can't conlude anything from the picture shape in that case.

Comment: Just checked with GeoGebra: your output is right.

Comment: @Martigan  You're right. I need to add some input validation to confirm the input represents my picture. Thx.